# Issue with Django 3 and jupyter

Tags: django

I am trying to to use jupyter note with django3 but I am getting this error, can anyone help me this. I m stuck on this part.

Comment: Need more clarity with your question. Can you post what exactly error/problem you are trying to solve ?

Comment: SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.